# i was creating a register and login with txt file but somehow was not able to login multiple user but only single last registered is working

Tags: php, html

i have created a login and register form with txt file and it is only comparing with last entered record not with previous

this is my register code

```
<?php
$fn=$_REQUEST["txtfname"];
$ln=$_REQUEST["txtlname"];
$un=$_REQUEST["txtuname"];
$p=$_REQUEST["txtpass"];
$cp=$_REQUEST["cpass"];
$e=$_REQUEST["txtemail"];
$ph=$_REQUEST["txtphone"];
$data="$fn/$ln/$un/$p/$e/$ph//";
$fp=fopen("user.txt","a");
fwrite($fp,$data);
fclose($fp);
header("location:home.php?id=ar");
?>
```

and this is my login code

```
<?php
$name=$_REQUEST["txtusername"];
$pass=$_REQUEST["txtpassword"];
if( file_exists("user.txt") &&  filesize("user.txt")>0)
{
    $fp=fopen("user.txt","r");
    $str=fread($fp,filesize("user.txt")-2);
    $arr=explode("//",$str);
    fclose($fp);
foreach($arr as $rec)
{
    $row=explode("/",$rec);
}
while(!feof($fp)){
if((trim($row[2])==$name) && (trim($row[3])==$pass))
{
    if(isset($_POST["chk"]))
    {
    setcookie("auth",$name,time()+60*2); 
    }
    else
    {
    setcookie("auth",$name); 
    }
    
     header("location:home.php?id=ls");
    }
}

else if($name="" && $pas=="")
{
    header("location:home.php?id=fl");
}
else
{
    header("location:home.php?id=fl");
}
}
}
?>
```

i have created a form where i have passed username and pass with name

Comment: This is a daft way to store the data. Just use a database, it's why they exist.

Comment: i know but i want to try it with file

Comment: Why? It will only cause you problems and inefficiencies, and there are no benefits. If this is a purely academic exercise to see what would happen, then ok fine you can do it as an experiment, but don't try to use it in a real website.

Comment: Anyway your logic error is in `foreach($arr as $rec)
{
    $row=explode("/",$rec);
}`...here you loop through all the records, but you don't do anything else inside the loop. So by the time you've finished looping all the records, `$row` contains the value of the last record. Anything you execute after the loop can only see that last record. If you want to check each record individually, that needs to happen inside your `foreach` loop.